Fortify Cross-Site Script DOM Finding | Proper way to handle the finding
We have a Fortify finding for: Cross-Site Scripting DOM.
Here is the code:
function applyFormatting(ruleObject) {
    element = ruleObject.TargetElement

    if (element) {
        if (ruleObject.BackgroundColor) {
            $(element).css('background-color', ruleObject.BackgroundColor); 
        }
        if (ruleObject.TextColor) {
            $(element).css('color', ruleObject.TextColor); 
        }
    }
}

It is a finding on line         $(element).css('background-color', ruleObject.BackgroundColor); and $(element).css('color', ruleObject.TextColor);.
For ruleObject.TextColor and ruleObject.BackgroundColor
Example values in the database are: #f52f3c and #1896f0
You cannot write normal InjectSafeHTML code because of the # of the color hex code that is required.
What is a valid way to handle this finding?
This is a requirement of our application.

You can handle the Fortify finding by sanitizing and validating the ruleObject.BackgroundColor and ruleObject.TextColor values before applying them to CSS properties. Use a JavaScript object to map acceptable color values and check against this object to prevent injection of malicious code while allowing legitimate color customization.
